# why do lm() and plm() give different Std. errors when combined with vcovHC? And other doubts

Tags: r, regression, least-squares, standard-error, plm

I'm attending an introduction course to econometrics and I have to solve some empirical exercises with r, but I have some doubts.
These two formula compute the same coefficients, the same std. Errors and the same R2 and adj. R2:

```
data(Seatbelts)
SeatBelts.p <- pdata.frame(SealtBelts, index = c("state", "year"))

myols_plm.pool <- plm(formula = fatalityrate ~ sb_useage + speed65 + speed70 + ba08 + drinkage21 + log(income) + age, data = SeatBelts.p, model = "pooling")
myols_lm <- lm(formula = fatalityrate ~ sb_useage + speed65 + speed70 + ba08 + drinkage21 + log(income) + age, data = SeatBelts.p)
```

Why are they identical? What does the intercept mean here? Why if I use the vcovHC matrix for both the model the std. errors differ? I read somewhere that with plm objects vcovHC() computes clustered standard errors and this is an explanation but with examples below I obtain different results.

If I want to add the individual fixed effects I have three possibilities:

```
myols_plm.pool.individual <- plm(formula = fatalityrate ~ sb_useage + speed65 + speed70 + ba08 + drinkage21 + log(income) + age + factor(state) - 1, data = SeatBelts.p, effect = "individual", model = "pooling")
myols_lm.individual <- lm(formula = fatalityrate ~ sb_useage + speed65 + speed70 + ba08 + drinkage21 + log(income) + age + factor(state) - 1, data = SeatBelts.p)
myols_plm.within.individual <- plm(formula = fatalityrate ~ sb_useage + speed65 + speed70 + ba08 + drinkage21 + log(income) + age, data = SeatBelts.p, model = "within")
```

The three formula above are equivalent: same estimates, FE (for the "within" model I have to use fixef()) and std. errors but each one of them computes a different R2/adj. R2; Why? With plm() what is the difference between "within" and "pooling" model? But above all, mainly with regard to the two plm model, Why with vcovHC() I obtain different Std. errors? They are similar but not equal.

Thanks in advice for your help.